# Symfony2 on Windows with Apache, PHP and MySQL - app_dev.php will not load

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, mysql, php, symfony

I am trying to get a Symfony2 standard distribution to work on my Windows 7 laptop.

I have installed Apache2 (version 2.2.22), PHP 5.3.10 and MySQL 5.5.22.

I have a demo PHP script (php_info() and a database call), and it works fine.

I can get the start page (http://localhost/Symfony/web/config.php) to display, but I cannot get http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/ to execute.

The error returned is Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.

I can get it to work if I install XAMPP instead, but I don't want to use XAMPP. I want to be able to install and configure the components separately.

Why isn't this working?

Are there some Apache settings that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a super strange bug:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60758

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3216

TL;DR Your git is converting line endings to CRLF on pull, which makes the vendors file TwigEngine.php exactly 4096 bytes which crashes PHP on include/require.

The workaround is to remove your vendors (or just symfony). Set your git config to not convert line endings:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

And install vendors.